# What is a simple and low-profile way to do push notifications in an ASP.NET MVC app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, push-notification

I need a way for my web application to send push-notifications to the client side. Realtime is not a strong requirement, near-realtime is okay. I don't need anything fancy, just sending a string to the client every now and then, nothing more. What's really important is that the solution must be very simple and low-profile (performance-wise mainly). Could you give me advice on which framework to use?

Many people would say SignalR hands down, but I'm not sure about the performance part. It is not disqualified, I'll tell about my doubts below, and I'm also interested about any insights you may have about this, but the main question stays what I wrote above.

I read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27107/Scalable-COMET-Combined-with-ASP-NET) recently. What it provides is a long-running request pattern with only a few classes, a little IIS & async magic and nothing more. Even if you have an IIS connection limit of 200, it will barely use up any of those connections. Compared to this, SignalR is as complex and heavy-weight as a nuclear power plant. It comes with half a dozen different DLL's (like OWIN, which I haven't heard about before, and even after a bit of Googling, I can't figure out what it is). The [performance wiki page](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Performance) of SignalR starts by suggesting to increase your concurrent request limit to a ridiculous amount. So I'm guessing it's not using the aforementioned "trick". I'm not exactly sure how bad that is, but in the light of that article, it doesn't sound good.

Comment: Client is mobile-app or web-app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since noone answered about the resource requirements and my doubts about SignalR, which was the key question here, I'm accepting this as an answer: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27107/Scalable-COMET-Combined-with-ASP-NET .

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to push messages to the client, SignalR approach is very good. As far as I know it works with web-sockets. Try to digg this way. Here is some article for the beginning:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2012/07/17/building-real-time-web-apps-with-asp-net-webapi-and-websockets.aspx.

For mobile apps I would use great library **PushSharp**. https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp
With help of PushSharp you can send notifications to any mobile app: WindowsPhone, IOS, Android, Blackberry etc.

Please note: sending push notification differs from platform to platform.

Keep in mind approach with pinging server all the time and checking for new messages. It is probably the easiest way.

Comment: If I need to use two different libraries, then it is anything but simple, I tried to emphasize in my question that simplicity is very important.

Comment: PushSharp is for sending special push notifications for the platform. Not messages like you want... I think you should somehow use websockets. Try to find some lib which wraps it and it will be ok for the server. Mobile platforms supports websockets so they will have to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

I use SignalR and toastr.js.  SignalR can scale to thousands of connections.  There are also native SignalR clients for iOS and Android (check out Signalr-ObjC).

Comment: My problem about scaling is that SignalR *needs* that many connections, and based on that article I cited, it doesn't have to be like that. So the real question is if my doubts are justifiable or not.